# NPM is creating ton of cmd and ps1 files

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using Windows 10 laptop, recently, I started getting the .cmd and .ps1 files getting created in the root Node js application.

It looks like the contents of node_modules/.bin/ folder are entirely pushed to  root folder.

I have tried to uninstall and install the Node but no luck. I tried to install the latest Node and also Node 12.x.x but I am still getting the same issue.
I tried to create a fresh Node js application too. Any ideas, please?

[image]